# Deleting a picture being sent by whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

How do delete a picture that has started sending on whats app  but hasn't completed

Answer (score 1):

When sending whatsapp image there will be cancel symbol only till file is not uploaded to Whatsapp servers, [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2LP5.jpg) is the cancel symbol for reference.

If Image gets uploaded you have to use Delete for everyone feature for removing the Image.